# MySQL join and associative array?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a MySQL join like so,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT m.* a.username FROM mailbox m JOIN accounts a (m.msgFrom = a.id) WHERE msgTo = ? AND sent = '0'");
$q -> execute(array($user['id']));
while ($msg = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo $msg['username'];
}
```

I would like to pull the users' username from the table accounts rather than just display the id from the table mailbox, I get the array performing a while loop on the query,

This doesn't seem to work though, any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to pull the rows from the result.

Comment: That is performed in the while loop it still fails though

Comment: Doesn't look it to me. And "fails" isn't a diagnosis.

Comment: Yes it is, the error exception is mysql fail violation 1064

Comment: run the php typeof command on the data returned to make sure its not null and its of the right type. ?

Comment: An error message is not a diagnosis.

Comment: And your explanation to back up your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `on` in the join condition try this:

```
SELECT m.*, a.username 
FROM mailbox m JOIN accounts a on (m.msgFrom = a.id) 
WHERE msgTo = ? AND sent = '0'
```